# Ruby/Rails : Can't play HLS/.m3u8 Media using video_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently, I am trying to play some asset and them have `.m3u8` extension but when I tried to embed them in video_tag they won't play.

do I need other plugins/gems to play it ? or it just needs some configuration?

Comment: How does the generated HTML look like? Does the video play if your write the HTML manually and do not use the `video_tag` helper? What is the error (invalid format, file not found, ...)?

Comment: i've tested from chrome and firefox, them give me no clue what's the error. basically the video won't play. but when I tested it on safari it worked.

Comment: And how does the generated HTML code look like?

Comment: i've create a gist file sir , https://gist.github.com/rahmatullah5/11e3dd4810f9f7486f2adef8b99b057e